# How to add actions like toggle button to change the value of some fields in list view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I want to add editable field in ListView like `<BooleanInput />` to change the value of some field in the list view. But after read through docs I couldn't find any idea.Because right now the only thing I can do with List view is non editable field like `<BooleanField />, <TextField />`,...
Please give some advice or idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish with this?

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your question properly so it is clear to the community what exactly do you want to achieve and what exactly is the issue you are referring to.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would like to have <BooleanInput /> in List view instead <BooleanField /> to change the value direct from ListView otherwise I have to go to edit page to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit these entries inside the List, the following article shows how to put Edit inside the List: https://marmelab.com/blog/2019/01/09/react-admin-2-6.html#datagrid-expansion-panel

```
const UserEdit = props => (
   <Edit 
       {...props}
       /* disable the app title change when shown */
       title=" "
    >
       <SimpleForm
           /* The form must have a name dependent on the record, because by default all 
           forms have the same name */
           form={`post_edit_${props.id}`}
       >
           <TextInput source="name" />
       </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);

const UserList = props => (
    <List {...props}>
       <Datagrid expand={<UserEdit />}>
           <TextField source="id" />
           <TextField source="name" />
           <TextField source="role" />
       </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```